# possible to run idlex without a heartbeat (i want to minimize number of windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-idle

when i start idlex from a command prompt (Windows), i lose my prompt to the new process until i close idlex.

```
F:\>c:\Python27\Scripts\idlex.py
[IPKernelApp] To connect another client to this kernel, use:
[IPKernelApp] --existing c:\users\myname\appdata\local\temp\tmpch1j8w.json
heartbeat: 1.0
```

i want to see only the idlex gui and not this heartbeat info. is this possible ?
initially i thought running with '-n' would work, but the result is not what i thought i might be.

Answer (score 2):

You can get your console back by launching the program with `pythonw` instead of `python`. The `pythonw` interpreter doesn't use the standard input and output file handles, so it doesn't need a console window to be open for those.

The best way to get a script to always use `pythonw` is to rename its extension from `.py` to `.pyw`. That should also work if you launch it from an explorer window or shortcut, rather than from the console directly.

Comment: IdleX already includes an idlex.pyw in the scripts directory.